# ¿Cómo le hago para insertar en un archivo de texto lo que escribí en 2 entradas de datos? Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Miren, en la universidad me enseñaron un código el cual funciona para guardar en un archivo de texto los datos que escribo en una entrada de datos, pero de tarea nos dejaron que hagamos un programa el cual use dos entradas de datos y se guarden en el mismo apartado. El problema es que no se cómo hacerlo, es muy confuso, ya tengo horas programando una página web y al pasar a hacer este programa me siento bloqueado y capaz sea un problema sencillo pero no me puedo dar cuenta.

El trabajo que me encargaron:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código y ejecución de mi y programa:
[Código](https://uanledu-my.sharepoint.com/:o:/g/personal/rafael_cavazosmrt_uanl_edu_mx/EvywNbaOzFRKu3-QOJ7niXUB8ELGls23TuMxDLKiszMpnA?e=6mzgnD)

Y como ven lo que quiero hacer es que en lugar de una entrada de datos, haya dos: La del nombre y la del teléfono.

Comment: El codigo tenes que pegarlo aca y estas con Xamarin.Forms, no xamarin.Android

Comment: Mirando el codigo no tiene nada que ver con lo que colocas. El otro es un ingreso de notas y vos mostras una agenda.

Comment: Si, el caso es ese, puse el código del programa de notas, para enseñar que lo que quiero es hacer un programa con el mismo código, la diferencia que en lugar de tener solo una entrada de datos que es el texto de la nota, haya 2 entradas el Nombre y Teléfono de una agenda, pero que se guarde en un mismo lugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el caso de queres hacer dos entradas en tu xaml, agregas dos componentes Entry que son cajas de texto.

```
   <StackLayout Margin="10,35,10,10"> 

    <Label Text="Notes" 

           HorizontalOptions="Center" 

           FontAttributes="Bold" /> 
    
   <Entry x:Name="txt_Nombre" 

            Placeholder="Nombre" 

            HeightRequest="100" /> 
   <Entry Placerholder="Telefono" x:Name="txt_telefono"/>

    <Grid> 

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 

        <Button Text="Guardar" 

                x:Name="OnSaveButton" 

                Clicked="OnSaveButton_Clicked"/> 

        <Button Grid.Column="1" 

                Text="Eliminar" 

                x:Name="OnDeleteButton" 

                Clicked="OnDeleteButton_Clicked"/> 

    </Grid> 

</StackLayout>
```

//En C#, tenes que concatenar esas dos cajas de texto.

```
   void OnSaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { 

        File.WriteAllText(_fileName, txt_Nombre.Text + " " + txt_elefono.Text); 

    }
```

Comment: Gracias!!!! Me has salvado mi Proyecto final del Semestre, te agradezco mucho!